# Navigate to Mainactivity from Navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want there to be a way to get back to the MainActivity from the nav when I switch fragments. The way I was trying to do it before was causing the app to crash. The main screen is the main activity.

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    Fragment fragment = null;

    Class fragmentClass;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.nav_inspi:
            fragmentClass = InFragment.class;
            break;

        default:
            fragmentClass = InFragment.class;
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fLayout_, fragment).commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    zDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            zDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    if (zDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in your code

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fLayout_, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```